# Regression prediction with combination of predictors

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regularization

I have one linear regression model: y ~ x1 + x2 (1) and now let $x_3 = x_1+x_2$, $x_4=x_1-x_2$, to form a new regression y ~ x3 + x4 (2), would the prediction of (1) and (2) be the same?

If I add L1 regularization to both models, would the prediction of (1) and (2) be the same?

Comment: Hey, x1 and x2 are vectors, if x1 = [1,1,1,1]' and x2 = [4,3,2,1]' then x3 = [5,4,3,2]', and x4 = [-3, -2, -1,0]'. We still have regress y on two predictors x3, x4.

Comment: @Dave I believe you misread the notation: the "(1)" and "(2)" look like they number the equations but are not part of the equations.